# Spring Integration concurrent ThreadpoolTaskExecutor, TaskRejectionException - Need to understand the reason for this error

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, threadpool, java.util.concurrent

I am using Spring Integration 2.0 with the below bean configuration for ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.

```
    <bean id="MyTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" destroy-method="destroy" >
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="25" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="25" />
        <property name="queueCapacity" value="0" />
    </bean>
```

I am starting to see the below error message in the application log. Need to understand what is happening in ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.

```
05-Mar-2020 11:34:36,389 |  ERROR |  |  |  |  |  |  | [org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler:handleError:100] | failure occurred in messaging task
org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@40102708[Running, pool size = 25, active threads = 25, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 13487163]] did not accept task: org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1@5de60ad1
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:244)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:174)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:51)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1@5de60ad1 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@40102709[Running, pool size = 25, active threads = 25, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 13487163]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:241)
    ... 11 more
```

Can some one identify the reason for this?

Comment: You have a maximum pool of 25 threads, when all those threads are busy then the thread pool will enqueue any additional requests until a thread is available, the problem is that your queue is of size 0. Even so, if the queue is not unbounded, you have to prepared for the thread pool to reject tasks that cannot simply be handled because the thread pool is fully booked at the moment. You can configure how you thread pool reacts to those events, either enqueuing, rejecting or simply discarding the task.

Comment: Does it mean that all the 25 threads are busy in processing the task and new tasks added to the ThreadPool is being rejected? I don't find all the 25 threads are being used as I don't 25 events are happening in my application in parallel. Is there a way to find those active thread details?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo , your comment deserves to be an answer. Please, consider to move it there, so anyone else with similar concern will know where to look.

Comment: @Arun , you need to share with us how you use that task executor: a big number for finished tasks says us that your app is indeed doing something